# Automatically Flag Question when only answer is put into LQP review

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, automatic-flags

While reviewing Low Quality Posts in the review queue, I am noticing a pattern that when the answer is the first (and only) answer to a question that is more than a few days old, it is usually a sign of a low quality question as well (regardless of the upvotes on the question).

For example, the only answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775734/alternative-testing-tool-than-tfs-with-vs-integration was automatically flagged as low quality, but the problem is not the answer, but the question itself.  It is a no-brainer tool request but had only managed 1 close vote in the first month (it has 2 now).  We need to get more attention to the bad answer so it can be closed.

We need to get these types of questions into a review queue.  Specifically, questions that get

- no answers for a period of time (for the sake of a number, let's say 2 weeks)
- an answer from a low rep user that merits an automatic low quality flag

Low rep users often try to snip rep by answering bad posts that everyone else ignored, so flagging these **questions** in addition to sending to the answer to the LQP's queue would help get eyes on the question so the question can be moderated appropriately.

Comment: Is this a problem on sites *other* than StackOverflow?

Comment: Are auto-VLQ flags on posts even still a thing?

Comment: @Mark possibly, I don't check a lot of other sites for this type of material.  But  the simple fact is bad answers to "old" questions that don't have existing answers are usually signs of a bad question, so the question may need some attention.  the purpose of this is to just make sure the question gets some attention so it can be moderated appropriately, be it edited, closed, voted, etc.